# Elmah integration - Error 500 when trying to access elmah.axd

Tags: asp.net, session, web-config, state, elmah

I'm trying to add the tool Elmah to my website to be able to log exceptions. Elmah is working since exceptions are logged into the table ELMAH_Error of my SQL Server Database.

The thing is, when I try to access the page elmah.axd, I get an Error 500. The problem is related to the sessionState which seems not to be activated. But if I look in the Web.config, I've got :

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" timeout="60" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
sqlConnectionString="data source=MYSERVER;Initial Catalog=ASPStateFicheClient;
user id=USERID;password=Password" cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

I'm working with .NET 3.5 and Webforms.

Here is the error shown on the website :

---

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[HttpException (0x80004005): Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration.]
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Session() +2650952
   MyFramework.HttpModules.ResultMessageModule.loadComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +67
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e) +8711878
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +735

Thank you in advance for you help,

Comment: What's `MyFramework.HttpModules.ResultMessageModule`? That doesn't look like part of ELMAH.

Comment: Waou... I delete the module in web.config and it's working... Now I've to find why the module avoids Elmah from working. Thank you very much ! :p

Comment: How are you securing your elmah page?